# Unable to start glassfish from netbeans after adding resources

Tags: xml, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I have working now with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Netbeans 7.3.1 on Windows 7 hungarian.

I have created the following simple glassfish-resource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <custom-resource res-type="java.util.Properties"
     jndi-name="iOIRConfig"
     factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory"
     description="iOIR konfigurációs beállítások">
     <property name="dev" value="false"></property>
  </custom-resource>
</resources>
```

**Look carefully on the description element - I have used accented hungarian characters - because this will be in the focus of my question and in this troubleshooting session.**

It is important to mention that the glassfish and netbeans environment was perfect before this experiment, so I could start, stop, deploy from command line and from netbeans as well. The XML was also excellent with the structure and the character set aspect as well.

So now I have tried to add that small resource into my clean glassfish domain with the asadmin command like this:

```
asadmin add-resources src\main\config\glassfish-resources.local.xml
```

this was the result:

```
remote failure: add-resources <glassfish-resources.local.xml> failed
Attribute "description" must be declared for element type "custom-resource".
Command add-resources failed.
```

I have modified each accented charters with an apropriate ASCII character like this:

```
  ...
  <custom-resource res-type="java.util.Properties"
     jndi-name="iOIRConfig"
     factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory"
     description="iOIR konfiguracios beallitasok">
  ...
```

The result was the same:

```
remote failure: add-resources <glassfish-resources.local.xml> failed
Attribute "description" must be declared for element type "custom-resource".
Command add-resources failed.
```

so I did a small modification on the XML like this:

```
<custom-resource res-type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="iOIRConfig" factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory">
  <description>iOIR konfiguracios beallitasok</description>
  <property name="dev" value="false"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

and look the miracle when I have tried to add with the asadmin add-resource command the result was good:

```
Command : Custom Resource iOIRConfig created.
Command add-resources executed successfully.
```

No I wanted to modify the description back to the accented characters like this:

```
<custom-resource res-type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="iOIRConfig" factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory">
  <description>iOIR konfigurációs beállítások</description>
  <property name="dev" value="false"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

Of course I have deleted the resource before I have applied the add-resource command again. The results was also good so wanted to see some deployment as well from netbeans.

The behavior of netbeans was so frustrating. It could stop the domain from the services panel but never started again. But starting and stoping the domain using asadmin was perfect during the all experiment.

I have played also with the description part of the properties as well. I have added more properties to try what happens.

The add-resource command was also sensitive how I declared the description part for the property but at the properties I could use accented charaters without any side effect. But only in this way:

```
<property name="dev" value="false">
  <description>Fejlesztési üzemmód</description>
</property>
```

I have also tried to modify the description of the custom resource using glassfish admin console to see if any difference exists. Not the problem exactly the same.

So I think I will use alway only ASCII characters in glassfish-resources.xml definitions until I will find a proper answer or somebody helps me to understand this really strange situation.